# Image set in text box just like placeholder in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to hide a certain image while having a textbox filled in and when the textbox is cleared I want to show a certain image. I know it should work something like this but with image instead of placeholder:

```
$('input:text').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your kind answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$('input:text').focus(function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'none');

}).blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).css('background', 'url(http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/71158_111108655596607_6920099_n.jpg) no-repeat left top');
    }
});
```

[**Check Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eSGML/)

With backspace key -

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eSGML/2/)

Comment: Thanks for reply but not focus time but keypress time when input key through keyboard image will hide and when backspace for this input text image will show...

Comment: Hello Dipak Good but please check..Reproduce Ex: input : 123456 then backspace key put 6 time then not show image....thanks reply